# Another PHP if/else not working as expected

Tags: php

I haven't been able to find a solution to this issue and hope that a another set of eyes may pick up on something. The else $confirm = line is not executed when the first "if" is not true and I can't figure out why.

```
if($_POST['zip'] && $_POST['country']=='USA' && !empty($fax)){
    $plus4 = substr($_POST["zip"],6,4);
    if (empty($plus4)) {
        $link = '<a href="http://zip4.usps.com/zip4/welcome.jsp?city='.$city.'&address2='.$address.'&state='.$state.'&zip5='.$zip.'" class="greybox" onclick="window.scrollTo(0,0)">Zip + 4</a>';
        $msg = "Your Zip + 4 was not provided! We cannot fax your Representative without your Zip+4.<br/>Click here to find your ".$link ;
        print "<p style=\"color: red;\"><b>$msg<br/><br/></b></p>";
    }
    if (empty($_POST['state']) || empty($_POST['zip'])) $statezip = false ; // Check for State & Zip Required
    else $statezip = true ;
    //if (empty($state) || empty($zip) || empty($plus4)) $statezip = false ; // Check for State & Zip Required
    $confirm = !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['from']) && !empty($_POST['address']) && !empty($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['country']) && $statezip == true ; // Verify required fields
}
else $confirm = !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['from']) && !empty($address) && !empty($city) && !empty($country) && $statezip == true ; // Verify required fields
```

Comment: You have inspected the contents of `$_POST['zip'],$_POST['country'],$fax` via `var_dump()`?

Comment: Thats a bit of a mess, will pay to properly seperate out the if statements

Comment: Does it make any difference that you're accessing `$address` instead of `$_POST['address']`.

Comment: to make sure your else condition runs as you want you should put the code inside curly brackets, e.g. `else { .... }`, the same as you do with it.

Comment: Are any of those supposed to be elseif's??

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` statement will always return `false` for `$confirm` due to the last condition:

```
&& $statezip == true
```

You are setting that value in the `if` statement, so it is undefined in the `else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Add your curly braces to the ELSE statement. Since you use them in the defining IF, the parser is expecting them.

```
else {
$confirm = !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['from']) && !empty($address) && !empty($city) && !empty($country) && $statezip == true ; // Verify required fields
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use isset to check that variable exist,
function empty return true even if it contain `0` ,
when you are using else use brackets `{` too
`else{do something}`